# Converting a raw list of IDs to a consolidated array of ids

Tags: ruby

I feel I have overcomplicated the process. What can I do to improve the following code?

```
ids = []

File.open(filePath, "r").each_line do |line|
  i += 1

  parts = line.split(',')

  parts[1] = parts[1].to_i
  parts[2] = parts[2].to_i

  # If the id doesn't exist in our ids array then create it and add the
  # second id else delete the second id and merge it into the new id
  unless defined? ids[parts[2]]
    # Instantiate the array first
    ids[parts[1]] = [] unless defined? ids[parts[1]]

    # Add the new id to the array
    ids[parts[1]].push(parts[2])
  else
    # Move over older ids that matched these to the new one
    if ids[parts[1]].nil?
      unless ids[parts[2]].nil?
        ids[parts[1]] = ids[parts[2]]
      else
        ids[parts[1]] = [parts[2]]
      end
    else
      unless ids[parts[2]].nil?
        ids[parts[2]].each do |id|
          ids[parts[1]].push(id)
        end
      end
    end

    # Insert the old id into the new array
    ids[parts[1]].push(ids[parts[2]])

    # Delete the old one
    ids.delete(parts[2]) unless ids[parts[2]].nil?
  end
end
```

The file I am processing is being generated by a deduping library, [Duke](https://github.com/larsga/Duke).

I am trying to consolidate the matches it has generated into a grouped list of matched ids, so all common ids are grouped together. The file itself is 2.4G.

The point of consolidating this is that these are many purchases that have been ran through a deduplication process to product a single customer. I feel it would be easier to consolidate this list rather than building up the customer and continually add purchases to it. This is a one time process.

Here's the first 100 lines from the file I'm consolidating. The format of which is:

> `MATCH (-/+), ID1, ID2, PROBABILITY %`
>
> ```
> +,6,7,0.9997260166738423
> +,3,4,0.9997260166738423
> +,8,9,0.9997260166738423
> +,9,8,0.9997260166738423
> +,7,6,0.9997260166738423
> +,6,10,0.9997260166738423
> +,4,3,0.9997260166738423
> +,10,6,0.9997260166738423
> +,8,296,0.9986244841815681
> +,6,39,0.9983391066412223
> +,8,299,0.9986244841815681
> +,7,10,0.9997260166738423
> +,6,40,0.9983391066412223
> +,9,296,0.9986244841815681
> +,8,1101,0.9986244841815681
> +,10,7,0.9997260166738423
> +,6,1081,0.9983391066412223
> +,6,1083,0.9983391066412223
> +,10,39,0.9983391066412223
> +,10,40,0.9983391066412223
> +,10,1081,0.9983391066412223
> +,10,1083,0.9983391066412223
> +,8,1125,0.9997260166738423
> +,8,1128,0.9997260166738423
> +,9,299,0.9986244841815681
> +,8,1132,0.9997260166738423
> +,9,1101,0.9986244841815681
> +,9,1125,0.9997260166738423
> +,9,1128,0.9997260166738423
> +,7,39,0.9983391066412223
> +,8,1144,0.9986244841815681
> +,8,1149,0.9986244841815681
> +,7,40,0.9983391066412223
> +,9,1132,0.9997260166738423
> +,7,1081,0.9983391066412223
> +,7,1083,0.9983391066412223
> +,9,1144,0.9986244841815681
> +,9,1149,0.9986244841815681
> +,12,24781,0.9997260166738423
> +,11,16,0.9999872532595235
> +,17,15,0.9997260166738423
> +,16,11,0.9999872532595235
> +,7,36,0.9977532413823246
> +,6,36,0.9977532413823246
> +,10,36,0.9977532413823246
> +,15,17,0.9997260166738423
> +,18,560,0.99892382632337
> +,59,56,0.9997260166738423
> +,37,36,0.9997260166738423
> +,37,1333,0.9997260166738423
> +,37,1341,0.9997260166738423
> +,37,12479,0.9997260166738423
> +,37,19462,0.9997260166738423
> +,37,19466,0.9997260166738423
> +,70,64,0.9997260166738423
> +,70,106,0.9997260166738423
> +,27,8200,0.9999217037269025
> +,28,397,0.9981390956560382
> +,27,8229,0.9999217037269025
> +,49,145,0.9991644138608996
> +,49,19596,0.9998336350736409
> +,49,250925,0.9991644138608996
> +,64,70,0.9997260166738423
> +,64,106,0.9997260166738423
> +,26,22,0.9999217037269025
> +,27,66061,0.9990737249986892
> +,27,69613,0.9990737249986892
> +,27,69617,0.9990737249986892
> +,27,70011,0.9990737249986892
> +,23,613,0.9999217037269025
> +,27,70885,0.999849094020817
> +,23,1186,0.9999217037269025
> +,77,87,0.9997260166738423
> +,23,1274,0.9999217037269025
> +,22,26,0.9999217037269025
> +,23,7603,0.9999217037269025
> +,27,70946,0.9990737249986892
> +,23,7759,0.9996066089693157
> +,23,7766,0.9996066089693157
> +,95,100,0.9997260166738423
> +,95,12510,0.9997260166738423
> +,23,12437,0.9996066089693157
> +,23,12455,0.9996066089693157
> +,23,32083,0.9999217037269025
> +,39,40,0.9997260166738423
> +,39,1081,0.9997260166738423
> +,40,39,0.9997260166738423
> +,39,1083,0.9997260166738423
> +,40,1081,0.9997260166738423
> +,40,1083,0.9997260166738423
> +,39,36,0.9996291897994778
> +,39,37,0.9996291897994778
> +,40,36,0.9996291897994778
> +,39,1333,0.9996291897994778
> +,40,37,0.9996291897994778
> +,39,1341,0.9996291897994778
> +,40,1333,0.9996291897994778
> +,39,1352,0.9997851370603088
> +,114,108,0.9997260166738423
> +,40,1341,0.9996291897994778
> ```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Could you please add some background information about why you wrote this code, and what problem it solves for you? (Not just the mechanics of what it does, but also the big picture.)

Comment: As 200_success said, it'd be nice to know what the overall purpose of this code - i.e. its context. It'd also be very nice to have an example of the input (the file it's reading), and the output. Otherwise we have to work backward from the code, which is tedious and error-prone.

Comment: Follow-up: I actually tried working backwards and create some sample input, but I get nonsensical output (arrays filled with `nil` nested inside other arrays inside other arrays)... or the script just hangs. So yeah, we need some more clues here.

Comment: Sorry about that, I've updated the question. Thanks for looking into it regardless of the ambiguous information :)

Comment: Thanks for the update, but I seem to be getting the same issues using your code and sample data. I can get it to go through the first 11 lines (and I get the funky recursively nested arrays), but with 12 lines, it just hangs. So something's not quite right.

Comment: You are correct, I didn't realise it was doing that. I just assumed it was crunching through the entire file. I'll debug my end and get back with some updated code.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry to say that your code is pretty irretrievably broken. I've posted an answer even though the proper procedure would be to close your question (only working code is on-topic). But there was too much going on in that code to leave it alone.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by consolidating? I don't understand your task. Do you want to take your file, and for each row, put it in an array with other lines that have the same field 1 and field 2?

Comment: While I'm glad someone answer your question and helped you, this is not really the site for this. I vote to close your question since it's broken code. You don't need to delete it, just it would be a bad example to leave it open. I do hope you'll rejoin us with some code ready to review (code working and etc)! I'm learning ruby and wow there is a lot to learn!

Answer (score 3):

Your code is very, very broken. Technically, that means it's [not a question for CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). However, I'll review it anyway, only because it's, well, it's fascinatingly broken.

---

*Name your variables.* Right now, it's really difficult to keep track of things, because `parts[1]` and `parts[2]` is pretty obtuse. They're obviously integer IDs, but what's their relation to each other?

Reading it felt something like this:

> There's an ID and an ID and an array, and if the ID - yeah, that one - is in the array, then add the ID - no, that one - but if the ID isn't...  wait

A comment like this doesn't really help:

```
# If the id doesn't exist in our ids array then create it and add the
# second id else delete the second id and merge it into the new id
```

I'm sorry, but what? What is "the id", and "the second id", and "the new id"? All I have is `parts[1]` and `parts[2]`.

Secondly, don't use `unless...else`. Ruby's `unless` is great for *single* conditional statements like `doStuff unless x`, but if you're going to have an `else` branch, just use a regular old `if..else`. Otherwise the `else` branch reads like a double-negative: "If not, do this; else if *not* not, do this". It gets confusing in a hurry.

Now, as to why it's actually broken, and not just hard to read:

[`defined?`](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-defined-3F) doesn't do what you think it does. If you've got an array `a = [1,2,3]`, and you try `defined?(a[21315])` what do you get? The string `"method"`. Which is truthy. So the entire first branch *never runs*. Checking for `nil?` is what you want to be doing, and you do that in other places - which, even if both approaches worked, also makes the code inconsistent.

And here's why it's *really* broken: [`Array#delete`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-delete). It, as the name suggests, deletes things. It removes the given index entirely, shifting all following indices one place. And you're relying on ids being equal to array indices. See the problem? You may have assigned something to `ids[23]`, but then you went and called `ids.delete(10)`, and what you previously assigned as `ids[23]` is now `ids[22]`. And the next time you go look up ID 23, you'll get get what used to be `ids[24]`.

So even *if* the code somehow worked, and chewed through your file, you'd get very, very wrong results.

Oh, and by the way, what is `i` doing? Why are you incrementing it?

Overall, I can't tell you what to do instead, because frankly I'm not even sure what it's supposed to do right now.

Comment: Thanks for the brutally honest answer. The I was left in there by accident when posting to this site, it has no relevance to the code at all.

Comment: I've been learning ruby around this, more specifically array manipulation, so I wasn't entirely sure what to do. I just thought I wrote it in a convoluted way, but after reading your post and your understanding of the problem I can see that I do indeed have some broken code. 

As this question does violate the off-topic rules what should I do, delete it or mark your answer as correct and come back later with working code if I feel it needs reviewing?

Comment: Absolutely feel free to come back if you want code reviewed! As for what to do with this question, I'd say you're free to close/delete it. Or I can mark it as off-topic, and a moderator can decide, but closing is probably the most appropriate. And best of luck learning Ruby - it's a lovely language. For this kind of problem, I **highly** recommend reading the documentation for Array and the Enumerable module it includes. I bet you'll find many useful methods

Comment: @AdamLavin In particular I think you will want `Enumerable#sort_by` and `Enumerable#chunk` together, if I am understanding your purpose (which I probably am not).  Sort the lines by `fields = line.split(","); "#{fields[1]}_#{fields[2]}"`